# Why isn't there numeric datatype for 0 - 4,294,967,294

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is probably a dumb question, and if so I apologize.

I was recently reading an article about setting your identity as IDENTITY(-2147483647,1) so that you get all 4 billion rows when using INT datatype, this feels very odd to me.

I was curious why there is not a datatype the same size as INT but holds 0 - 4,294,967,294 rows.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a duplicate of [this question on dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/78918/35474) and I can't mark it as such b/c the two questions are on different sites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the difference between an signed long integer and an unsigned long integer. Unsigned long integers would store the values between 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 and 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 or 0 to 4294967295, which is what your gut tells it should be.

Instead this is a signed Long Integer which uses the left most bit for the sign. 0 for positive, and 1 for negative. So you store values between 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 and 01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 or -2147483647 to 2147483647.

There's some nuance here on how the unsigned long stores negative numbers (using the 2's compliment). You can read more about it here http://kias.dyndns.org/comath/13.html

As for why Microsoft has decided to use signed ints instead of unsigned, you can check out the link by @alroc in the Question's comments, although it's not terribly illuminating since it basically comes down to "It's complex and we're cool it with it, so it's just how it is. Buck up."